# display none clears the textarea value

Tags: html, textarea

The contents of `<textarea>` seems to get cleared once I hide it with `display : none` and show it back again by removing `display`. Is there a way to retain the original value when the textarea shows again?

Comment: Could you post your code or a jsFiddle? And as you can see, that's not the proper behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/g9gSf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using jQuery or some other javascript framework. 
In case of jQuery the show and hide function do the magic for you.
​

```
<textarea cols="5" rows="5" id="test">Test</textarea>
<input type="button" value="switch on" onclick="$('#test').show();">
<input type="button" value="switch off" onclick="$('#test').hide();">​
```

Well, if you just remove the display, there might be some faults. You have to set it to inline  (in case of an inline element) or block (in case of a block element) if you want to make it visible again. The css-Property display can be set to none|inline|block. So if you set the display to none you should set it back to inline instead of removing the property afterwards.

Here is a solution w/o jQuery:

```
<textarea id="test">TEST</textarea>
<input type="button" value="switch on" onclick="showTest();"/>
<input type="button" value="switch off" onclick="hideTest();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function hideTest() {
    var field = document.getElementById('test');
    field.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function showTest() {
    var field = document.getElementById('test');
    field.style.display = 'inline';
  }

​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```